# Refreshing elements inside ul that find place in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, refresh, page-refresh

I have a div that contains a iframe from another website. In that website you can find a UL and its updates every time user adds a feedback. This is the ul:

Is it any way I can refresh only this ul every x seconds so I get the feedbacks in realtime?

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I see that I wasn't completely clear with what I meant and what I am going to use. I have Facebook comments on my website and I want the facebook comment field to be updates every 2 sec so new comments appear without needing user to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No if they are in a different domains. Using Javascript you can't get information from another website due the **[Same Origin Police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)**. It's a security restriction that browsers implements and you can't bypass.

> Same Origin Police policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port
>   number – to access each other's DOM with no specific restrictions, but
>   prevents access to DOM on different sites.

If you want to keep updated from another website you may need use a server side language (JAVA, PHP, NodeJS, etc...) to make a request, parse the return HTML from other website and find the information you need.

**EDIT:**

If you just need update the iframe every X seconds you can use setInterval:

```
  var refreshFrame= function () {
    var iFrames = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassName");
    for(var i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
      if(iFrames[i].className === "yourClassName") {
         iFrames[i].src = iFrames[i].src;
      }
    }
  }
  window.setInterval(refreshFrame, 3000); // Time in ms
```

look this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hq2xL6Ld/)

Comment: Thanks nanndoj. Ok I am sorry I see that I wasn't completely clear with what I meant and what I am going to use. I have Facebook comments on my website and I want the facebook comment field to be updates every 2 sec so new comments appear without needing user to refresh the page. Any suggestings on how i might do it?

Comment: Do you mean refresh the frame in X seconds?

Comment: Thanks. It cant be done since the iframe changes its name after every refresh. how can i do it with Class name?

Comment: Loop through all frames and compare if it has the cless name you want and refresh it

Comment: Thanks nanndoj. In Consol I got this error for every refresh attend: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8888" from accessing a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.untitled.php:10 refreshFrame

Comment: You are right. In the code document.frames will return the window obj referencing the frame (is DOM and will be blocked). You have to get the html element and change its src property.

Comment: Nanndoj, It couldnt bee done with that. Is it possible to make it so instead for refreshing a iframe it just refresh a DIV? :)